# How to make vim spell error search the current line only?

Tags: vim, spell-checking

This vim binding will make `<C-l>` correct the previous spelling mistake:

```
inoremap <C-l> <c-g>u<Esc>[s1z=`]a<c-g>u
```

How do I modify it to make it correct the previous mistake on the current line only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a shorter and better version of this answer [available on Stack Exchange here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/19792). The idea is the same, but the execution is better.

While the current solution works, the answer in the link above reuses exactly the original mapping.

---

**Original answer below**

I have been tinkering with different versions of your mapping and almost came up with a good solution (although it is quite inelegant) that needs to be added to your configuration file, as presented here:

```
function! FixLastSpellCurrentLine()
  let s:linenum1 = line('.')
  execute 'normal ms[s'
  let s:linenum2 = line('.')
  execute 'normal `s'
  if s:linenum1 == s:linenum2
      execute 'normal ms[s1z=`sl'
  endif
  let s:islastchar = col(".") == col("$")-1
  if s:islastchar
      :startinsert!
  else
      execute 'normal h'
      :startinsert
  endif
endfunction

imap <C-l> <esc>:call FixLastSpellCurrentLine()<CR>
```

This is probably not working as you would expect in all circumstances, but this is close enough that I feel it might inspire you or someone else to improve upon it. The idea is simply to check where the previous spelling mistake occurs and compare lines. I would think that this can be implemented more or less thinking along those lines, but I am still not convinced that this solution is ideal.

What it does:

- From your current cursor position, it goes to normal mode and calls the defined function.
- It then stores the value of the current line into `s:linenum1`.
- It marks the current position with `ms` and jump to the previous spelling mistake found in the file, if any.
- From there, it captures the line number again into `s:linenum2` to see if it differs.
- It goes back to where it was and determines if the line has changed. If it changed, it will return into insert mode to where the cursor was and will not correct any spelling error if it occurred on another line.
- If it didn't change, it will correct the spelling mistake and return to where the cursor was originally.

Comment: From a few tests, this works as intended, thanks! There is another shorter solution posted in the accepted answer here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/19790/how-to-make-vim-spell-error-search-the-current-line-only

Comment: Thank you for sharing that link! I was looking for a better solution and while trying to fit everything into the function may have been possible, I realize it makes more sense to add commands directly to the mapping instead.